# Difference between module os and module subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I made a script in Linux to dynamically auto-copy into folders through the `subprocess` module:

```
import sys
import subprocess


script = sys.argv
name = str(script[0])
print name

for i in range(0,10):
  fold = 'Lombriz'+str(i)
  subprocess.call(['mkdir',fold])
  subprocess.call(['cp',name,fold])
```

However when I try to execute this same script in the windows `cmd` by placing the correct windows commands, it throws the following error:

```
Error: subprocess.call subprocess.call (['mkdir', fold])
  [Error 2]: The system can not find the specified file.
```

After that I had to do the same script with the module `os.system` and it worked perfectly on windows.

My question is: Does the subprocess module not work in Windows?
Can one only use `os.system` in Windows?

Comment: Of course `subprocess` works on Windows. If you take a brief glance at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), there's extensive information about the differences between Windows and POSIX, which would hardly be there if the module didn't work on Windows. Also, you'd get an `ImportError` if it didn't exist on Windows.

Comment: Then why do I throw error when using subprocess in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) works just fine on Windows.

But on any platform, `subprocess` can't call programs that don't exist. And there is no program named `mkdir` (or `MKDIR.EXE`) on Windows. When you type that into a command prompt, it's handled as a special built-in command by `cmd.exe`.

And, even if it did exist, you wouldn't be calling it, because from the error message you clearly passed `' mkdir'`, with a space before the `m`, and there's no program with than name on any system.

If you read the docs for `subprocess`, you can see that there are two ways around this:

- Pass `shell=True`, so the command will be executed by the shell (`cmd.exe`), similar to `os.system` but better in a variety of ways. Usually when you use this flag, you want to use a string rather than a list of arguments with this like `run(f'mkdir {fold}', shell=True)`
- Explicitly call `cmd.exe`, like `run(['cmd', '/C', 'mkdir', fold])`

However, there's really no reason to use either `os.system` or `subprocess` here. If you want to make a directory, just call [`os.mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) (or, if you want to do it recursively, [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs). That's cross-platform, and about as simple as possible. And similarly, instead of running `cp` on Unix and `copy` on Windows, you can just [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) or its variants.